# Why DateFormatter doesn't work on Swift Console?

Tags: swift

I run the following code on the swift console, why the date is nil, on  the contrary, this code works very well on the playground.

```swift
import Foundation

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

let string = "2020-03-02T13:34:01+01:00"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-03-02T11:37:47+0100")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to print your **date.description** or **date.debugDescription** in console. That should work if the date is not nil!